# Newbie needs to force php page reload once

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this php file which I am using to control relays attached to the gpio pins of a Raspberry pi. I works well except that the icons do not update as desired when the gpio pins change state. THey do update as desired if I click the RELOAD button on the browser. I have tried using:
location.reload(true) but it only works if I put it in the html portion of the page code as its own button. I want the location.reload(true) to execute whenever I click one of the gpio icons. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance from a newbie.

Here is the php code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--TheFreeElectron 2015, http://www.instructables.com/member/TheFreeElectron/ -->

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Antenna Relays</title>
    </head>
 
    <body style="background-color: black;">
    <h1><p style="color:white"><font size="7">     
     &emsp; &emsp; ANTENNA SELECTOR
    </p>
    
    </font></h1>
    <!-- On/Off button's picture -->
    <?php
    $val_array = array(0,0,0,0);
    //this php script generate the first page in function of the file
    for ( $i= 0; $i<4; $i++) {
        //set the pin's mode to output and read them
        system("gpio mode ".$i." out");
        exec ("gpio read ".$i, $val_array[$i], $return );
    }
    //for loop to read the value
    $i =0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        //if off
        if ($val_array[$i][0] == 0 ) {
            echo ("<img id='button_".$i."' src='data/img/red/red_".$i.".jpg' onclick='change_pin (".$i.");'/>");
        }
        //if on
        if ($val_array[$i][0] == 1 ) {
            echo ("<img id='button_".$i."' src='data/img/green/green_".$i.".jpg' onclick='change_pin (".$i.");'/>");
        }    
    }
    ?>
     
    <!-- javascript -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "I want the location.reload(true) to execute whenever I click one of the gpio icons." Does this work? `<button onclick="location.reload(true);" />`

Comment: At the bottom of the `change_pin` function is where you would want to add `location.reload(true)`.

Comment: I can see that would be a good place for the 'location.reload(true)' function, but I think I am having a syntax problem. Can you let me know the precise and complete statement I should be using, including punctuation? I would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: It also occurs to me, can a javascript function, such as location.reload() be called from within a PHP code segment?

Comment: @arniep, once PHP generates the HTML it is sent to the browser as HTML. So as far as the browser is concerned the PHP doesn't even exist. And `location.reload();` should work at the end of `change_pin` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload